# Javascript scope addEventListener and this

Tags: javascript, scope, this, addeventlistener

I am a C# developer experimenting with JavaScript and I'm trying to get my head around the scope :)

I have the following code which contains an `addEventListener` in which I want to use a field from my object:

```
(function(window) {

    function Keyboard() {
        this.keys = {};
    }

    Keyboard.prototype.handle_keydown = function(args) {
        this.keys[args.keyCode] = true;
    }

    Keyboard.prototype.listen = function() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handle_keydown);
    }

    app.util.keyboard = new Keyboard();

})(window);
```

I would like to use the keys array in my hander, but understand that I cannot access is by using this, because this is the window in that context (correct?).
If I change it to

```
app.util.keyboard.keys[args.keyCode] = true;
```

it works, but I'm not sure that's a good way to fix it.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803195/addeventlistener-and-the-scope-of-this), which seems rather similar, but Im not sure how I can fit it into my example.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have to add the functions through prototype, can you place them in the Keyboard function instead?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a self-executing function?

Comment: @Musa I would like to call the listen function in a different function than where I create the Keyboard, so I think I have to?

Comment: @ClaytonMisura I think I'm doing it to also guarantee my variables scoped to the Keyboard 'class'?

Comment: That's true, and that seems like the responsible way to use it, just wondering.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

A few things:

- Most people will suggest something like `var self = this` because it's fast and easy.
- But `var self = this` does not separate the *view object* entirely from the *view logic*, which coming from a more formal C# background and looking at your code, sounds like something you want to do.
- In order to have the callback execute only when the event fires, wrap the handler in a function, so that it's evaluated right away, but only executed when and if a `keydown` event fires (see the code below).
- Understanding scope in JS: Whatever the execution context is, is also the current scope. Your listener was added in a method (called `listen`) on `Keyboard.prototype`, but the `keydown` event is actually fired on `window` -- the handler is executing in a different context than where it was defined; it's executing within the context of what is invoking it, in this case, `window`, so it's scoped to `window` unless you bind it to another object via `bind` or `apply` when it's defined.

In your code, `window` is the view a user's interacting with, and `Keyboard` is that view's controller. In MVC patterns like what you're probably used to in C#/.NET, views don't tell themselves what to do when things happen, controllers tell views what to do. So, if you were to assign a reference to the controller by using `var self = this` like so many do, the view would be managing itself -- but only for that specific handler for `keydown` events. This is inconsistent and would become hard to manage in a large project.

**A solution:**

```
Keyboard.prototype.listen = function() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        this.handle_keydown(e);
    }.bind(this), false);
}
```

**A better solution:**

```
Keyboard.prototype.view = window;

Keyboard.prototype.listen = function() {
    this.view.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        this.handle_keydown(e);
    }.bind(this), false);
}
```

**The best solution (until ES6 `class` is ready):**

```
// define
function addViewController(view) {

    function ViewController() {

        this.handle_keydown = function(args) {
            // handle keydown events
        };

        this.listen = function() {
            this.view.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
                this.handle_keydown(e);
            }.bind(this), false);
        };

        this.view = view;
        return this;

    }

    return new ViewController(view);

}

// implement
var keyboard = addViewController(window);
keyboard.listen();
```

- Note: `.bind()` is compatible with ECMAScript 5+; if you need a solution for older browsers, Mozilla has posted a great alternative to `.bind()` using `functions` and `.call()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

**Edit:** Here's what your instantiated `keyboard` object will look like using this new, modular solution: [image]

Comment: very clear answer but how to do if I need to use also `removeEventListener` ? I need a named function.. ho to use the `bind` thing?

Comment: @nkint Then just name that function and use it as the argument instead of the anonymous function used above. For example `addEventListener('keydown', handler)` instead of `addEventListener('keydown', function () {})`. This way, you can later remove it by reference.

Comment: But by doing this, you lose "this", because the scope (this) is changed to element that called event.

Comment: @nkint addEventListener("click", this.onclick.bind(this), false)

Answer (score 7):

```
Keyboard.prototype.listen = function() {
    var self = this;
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
       self.handle_keydown(event);
       // self is your Keyboard object. You can refer to all your properties from this
    });
}
```

**How this code works:**

1. We are creating variable self, which stores reference to `this` variable.
2. The inner function is a closure, hence it has reference to self.
3. When the closure function is called: `this` points to the dom object, while `self` points to keyboard object.
4. The closure is called with `event` as a parameter that we pass on to the member function of the keyboard object.

Comment: no, I dont think so, could you show me the complete code maybe?

Comment: @Raf: This is complete code. I am calling your object with the correct handle. The event handler, which is part of your object getting called. Where is the issue? We don't need any other change in your code.

Comment: Woops, sorry, now it works! Don't know what I did before, but its ok now.

Comment: Was not my downvote ;) So do I understand correctly that this creates a self variable referencing my keyboard that is scoped to the window? If so, would this cause problems if I use this 'self' pattern in another 'class' (causing self to be overwritten and not being my keyboard anymore)?

Comment: @Raf: Edited the answer with explanation. Thank you for accepting the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I think I understand it now! So the problem with self being overwritten cannot happen, because self is created within the closure of the function and only known in that closure then, right?

Comment: self is created in the containing function (listen). The closure function in inside 'listen', hence it has access to all the variables in 'listen'

Comment: The world is still here and I have learned some things about closure... What a great day! :)

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
function Keyboard() {
    this.keys = {};
    var self = this;
    this.handle_keydown = function(args) {
        self.keys[args.keyCode] = true;
    }
    this.listen = function() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.handle_keydown);
    }
}
app.util.keyboard = new Keyboard();
```

Comment: That means I'm not using the prototype way, but I want only one keyboard instance, so maybe thats not a problem? Prototype is also something very new for me :)