# Scope of this in Click Handler

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have something similar to the following but I get the error: "this._toggle is not a function"

```
function handler(){
  this._toggle();
}
SelectFX.prototype._toggle = function(){
   ...
   this.removeEventListener('click', handler);
}
this.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

which I'm guessing is to do with the scope that addEventListener creates,

I would of thought then that adding this to a variable would fix but this code:

```
var self = this;
function handler(){
  self._toggle();
}
SelectFX.prototype._toggle = function(){
   ...
   this.removeEventListener('click', handler);
}
this.addEventListener('click', handler);
```

But the above gives the error "Cannot read property '_toggle ' of undefined"

If I use an anonymous function like below for the click handler it works fine but I need to Remove the Click Event later on, please help

```
SelectFX.prototype._toggle = function(){
   ...
}
this.addEventListener('click', function(){
   this._toggle();  //Works fine but I need to remove this addEventListener later on
});
```

I've create a Gist here with the Full plugin https://gist.github.com/grassed/ce76d9b2a5fa6ab9e5be which centers around this.selPlaceholder.addEventListener( 'click', clickHandler);

Comment: I have an idea, but I can't really understand what exactly you're trying to do. What's the goal?

Comment: Can you post more complete code, it's unclear `this.addEventListener('click', handler);`, the `this` here is pointing to what.

Comment: Ive summarized the issue as the actual plugin is quite large I will try to add it somewhere

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript scope addEventListener and this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996263/javascript-scope-addeventlistener-and-this)

Comment: @JustusRomijn thats what Ive tried to follow although there isnt an example of not using an anonymous function as the click handler

Comment: You can use bind for that, ill give you an example in a sec

Comment: Detailled solutions by MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the native [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function to pass the object that should represent `this` in the function called. You can use that also for event listeners. In the example below, I pass in someObject to be `this` when `someListener` is being called.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("clickable-span");

var someObject = {
  clickCount: 0,
  someListener: function(){
    this.clickCount++;
    this.showCount();
    el.innerText = 'Click me again';
  },
      
  showCount: function(){
    document.getElementById('target-span').innerText = 'You clicked ' + this.clickCount + ' time(s)';
  }
}

// use bind to pass in what `this` should refer to in the someListener method
// we want `this` to point to someObject so we can use the clickcount and such
el.addEventListener(
  "click", 
  someObject.someListener.bind(someObject)
);
```

```html
<button id="clickable-span">Click me</button>
<hr />
<span id="target-span"></span>
```