# cant acces element initialized in another method

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(function() {
  var model = {
    currentCat: null,
    cats: [{
        name: "Felix",
        clickCounter: 0,
        srcImage: "cat0.jpg"
      },
      {
        name: "Lucas",
        clickCounter: 0,
        srcImage: "cat1.jpg"
      },
      {
        name: "Martin",
        clickCounter: 0,
        srcImage: "cat2.jpg"
      },
      {
        name: "Pedro",
        clickCounter: 0,
        srcImage: "cat3.jpg"
      }
    ]
  };

  var octopus = {
    init: function() {
      indexView.init();
      displayView.init();
    },
    getCats: function() {
      return model.cats;
    },
    getCurrentCat: function() {
      return model.currentCat;
    },
    setCurrentCat: function(cat) {
      model.currentCat = cat;
    },
    updateClickCounter: function() {
      model.currentCat.clickCounter++;
      displayView.render();
    }
  };

  var displayView = {
    init: function() {
      this.imgSection = document.getElementById("imageSection");
      this.catImg = document.getElementById("cat-img");
      this.catName = document.getElementById("cat-name");
      this.catCounter = document.getElementById("cat-counter");

      this.catImg.addEventListener("click", function() {
        octopus.updateClickCounter();
      })
      this.render()
    },
    render: function() {
      var cat = octopus.getCurrentCat();

      this.catName.textContent = cat.name;
      this.catCounter.textContent = cat.clickCounter;
      this.catImg.src = cat.srcImage;
    }
  };


  var indexView = {
    init: function() {

      this.list = $("#list")
      this.render();

    },
    render: function() {
      cats = octopus.getCats();
      for (i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        cat = cats[i];
        listElement = document.createElement("li");
        listElement.textContent = cat.name;

        listElement.addEventListener("click", (function(copyCat) {
          octopus.setCurrentCat(copyCat);
          displayView.render();
        })(cat));
      };
    }
  };



  octopus.init();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Cat clicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cat.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/cat.js"></script>

  <h1 id="header"> Gatitos! </h1>

  <div id="catIndex">
    <h2 id="indexTitle">Index</h2>
    <ul id="list">
      <!-- here we have the index with the cats names -->
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="imageSection">

    <h2 id="cat-name"></h2>
    <div id="cat-counter"></div>
    <img src="" id="cat-img">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

in the `displayView` object, I can only acces the html elements that I got with `getElementById` inside the method they were initialized in (I can acces `catImg` when I add the event listener in the `init` method). The problem comes when I try to acces those elements in the `render` method. When you run this it returns undefined when you call all the elements from the `init` method (`this.catImg`, `this.catName` and `this.catCounter`). Why does it return `undefined`?

Comment: use `document.createTextNode` to add text on created elements

Comment: @azad creating the text content is not the problem because I can't acces the element to which I would append that text node in the first place. When I try to do `this.catImg.src = cat.srcImage` it throws an error `cannot set property 'src' to undefined`

Comment: you are calling `displayView.render()` before `displayView.init()` in `indexView.render()`

Answer (score 1):

you have to `bind` 'this' to your event handler, check out [Javascript scope addEventListener and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996263/javascript-scope-addeventlistener-and-this) on how to scope `this` to your event listener.