# How do I access object that is inside an event

Tags: javascript

I have this object that carries some functions. At some point, I would like to hold an event and call this object within that event, but only if you call this object using this, is there any way to call it without this?

I haven't tried anything yet, because I couldn't find anything to help.

```
const cantaVideoModal = {
    click: null,
    target: null,
    urlVideo: null,
    config: function (c) {
        this.click = c.click;
        this.target = c.target;
        this.urlVideo = c.urlVideo;

        this.init();
    },
    init: function () {
        this.click = (this.click) ? document.querySelector(this.click) : null;
        this.target = (this.target) ? document.querySelector(this.target) : null;

        let btnCloseVideo = document.querySelector('[data-close-modal]');
        if(btnCloseVideo){
            btnCloseVideo.addEventListener('click', function(){
                //call modalAction object here using this
            })
        }
    },
    modalAction: function (act) {
        let elementClick = this.click;
        let elementtarget = this.target;

        if (elementClick) {
            elementClick.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (elementtarget) {

                    if(act === "toggle")
                        elementtarget.classList.toggle('in');

                    if(act === "show")
                        elementtarget.classList.add('in');

                    if(act === "hide")
                        elementtarget.classList.remove('in');
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you cannot use `this` is because you are in a function inside a `addEventListener`. I'm not sure why, but you can create a new object that refer to the current object, which can be used inside the annonymous functon. For more information on why you can't use `this` inside a `addEventListener` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15594889/5784924)

```js
const cantaVideoModal = {
    click: null,
    target: null,
    urlVideo: null,
    config: function (c) {
        this.click = c.click;
        this.target = c.target;
        this.urlVideo = c.urlVideo;

        this.init();
    },
    init: function () {
        this.click = (this.click) ? document.querySelector(this.click) : null;
        this.target = (this.target) ? document.querySelector(this.target) : null;

        let btnCloseVideo = document.querySelector('[data-close-modal]');
        if(btnCloseVideo){
            // we create a new variable that refer to the current content.
            var self = this
            btnCloseVideo.addEventListener('click', function() {
                //call modalAction object here using self.
                self.modalAction(/* some parameters */);
            })
        }
    },
    modalAction: function (act) {
        let elementClick = this.click;
        let elementtarget = this.target;

        if (elementClick) {
            elementClick.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (elementtarget) {

                    if(act === "toggle")
                        elementtarget.classList.toggle('in');

                    if(act === "show")
                        elementtarget.classList.add('in');

                    if(act === "hide")
                        elementtarget.classList.remove('in');
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.** I tried using an arrow function but couldn't get the code to work properly.